# Amazon EC2 TCP on port 80?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to my `EC2` instance  with `TCP` in **port 80** , but I couldn't.

Do I have to enable it somehow?

Under the Inbound Rules on my Security Group I have `http on port 80` and `SSH on port 22`.

I am connecting from a hardware device. Is there a way to check the `TCP` connection from the `terminal` on the mac ?

Is there something else I have to do?

The host that I type to connect is:

```
http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Maybe it's your app's issue, you can use `nmap` to check if 80 is open with `nmap ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p 80`

Comment: nmap or `telnet ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com 80`
Did you open this port in security group? 
[aws security](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

Comment: In AWS there is two level firewall one is cloud firewall and another one will be server level firewall. Please make sure 80 port is open in both firewall for your ip address.

Comment: Can you access port 80 from the instance itself? That is, login to the instance and go to the URL, or to `localhost`. That will avoid any potential networking/security group issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to ensure you have opened the firewall rules for your instance security group on TCP 80, 22 and that your IP address is listed.

Example would be :

0.0.0.0/0 TCP 80

Allow inbound HTTP access to the web servers from anywhere or restrict by opening to your IP address only. Use your public IP which can be obtained from https://www.whatismyip.com/